# "System program problem detected" retrieve report

Tags: 18.04

I get, on a new installed machine with Ubuntu 18.04 often the message: "System program problem detected" With a option "Report problem".

I could sent a to report the problem, but I also want to know the kind of problem myself. Can I get a copy of this report?  If so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The report is in your /var/crash directory.

It's an ordinary text file with the complete stack trace or core dump (as appropriate). You can open it with any text editor (vim, nano, gedit, etc.)

Comment: Thanks, I could view my report there. Solved.